# Simplifying $\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rational-functions, symbolic-computation, symmetric-functions

> Simplify $$\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}\,.$$

I tried very hard but I am not being able to solve it *easily* I opened up everything and multiplied all of it and got the answer -2. But it took me 1 hour and I also made many silly mistakes. Is there a quicker way than brute force?

Comment: Maybe you could have splited the fractions to make some differences of square, but I do not think there is any big shortcut

Comment: I think you walked the simplest way -- clearing the denominator ($(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ is the common denominator). Even $2\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}=\frac{b^2+c^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+
\frac{c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+
\frac{b^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}$  
$=\frac{(b^2+c^2)(b-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}-\frac{c+a}{a-b}-\frac{b+a}{a-c}$ doesn't help much as you have to re-factor the numerator $\sum\limits_{cyc} (b^2+c^2)(b-c)$ to $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ again either way. @Jack

Comment: @Alexey Burdin yes exactly

Answer (score 6):

Let
$$
f(a,b,c)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}
$$Observe $f$ is invariant under permutations: $f(a,b,c)=f(b,c,a)=f(c,a,b)$, etc. Further, observe $f(0,1,2)=f(1,0,-1)=-2$. In other words, $f$ evaluates to $-2$ at $12$ points, and $12$ is greater than the sum of the degrees of the numerator and denominator. Thus $f$ is identically constant (provided no two of $a,b,c$ are equal).

Comment: Since the sum of degrees of numerator and denominator is 4, will it be still correct if I find out only one solution say (0,1,2) since it generates a total of 6 points which is still greater than 4

Comment: I am not sure how finding $12$ points $(a,b,c)$ such that $f(a,b,c)=-2$ implies that $f(a,b,c)=-2$ identically.  For example, the polynomial $p(a,b,c)=a+b+c$ has degree $1$, and vanishes at infinitely many points, but obviously, $p(a,b,c)$ is not identically zero.  I think you need a stronger statement.  In your case, $$\tilde{f}(a,b,c)=-\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$$ also satisfies $\tilde{f}(0,1,2)=\tilde{f}(1,0,-1)=-2$, and $p$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Batominovski, it's a rational function not a polynomial.

Comment: @Integrand  How does that matter?  The rational function $$F(a,b,c)=\frac{\tilde{f}(a,b,c)}{(a+b+c)-(bc+ca+ab)}$$ also satisfies $F(0,1,2)=F(1,0,-1)=-2$, and $F$ is symmetric.

Comment: For one-variable rational functions $f(x)=p(x)/q(x)$, each equation $f(x)=r$ has a finite number of solutions, which I believe is $\max\{\deg(p),\deg(q)\}$ or fewer. I guess I had assumed a similar result is true for multivariable functions...

Comment: I will keep this up for a little longer while I see if it can be salvaged and if not, I will delete it. Thank you @Batominovski for pointing out the error.

Comment: @Integrand  I think it can be salvaged.  Suppose $$f(a,b,c)=\frac{p(a,b,c)}{q(a,b,c)}$$ where $p(a,b,c)$ and $q(a,b,c)$ are coprime polynomials.  Then, it can be easily seen that the degree of each variable of $p(a,b,c)$ and $q(a,b,c)$ is at most $3$.  If you can find a set $S$ such that $|S|>3$ such that $f(a,b,c)=-2$ for $(a,b,c)\in S\times S\times S$ such that $a\neq b\neq c\neq a$, then $f(a,b,c)=-2$ identically.  So, with $S:=\{-1,0,1,2\}$, you only need to check further that $f(-1,0,2)$ and $f(-1,1,2)$ are equal to $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using polynomials.  Note that $$\begin{align}S&:=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}
\\&=(a^2+b^2+c^2)\left(\frac{1}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{1}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{1}{(c-a)(a-b)}\right)
\\&\phantom{abc}-2\left(\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-c)(c-a)}+\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}\right)\,.\end{align}$$
Consider
$$p(x):=\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{(x-c)(x-a)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$
and
$$q(x):=a^2\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+b^2\frac{(x-c)(x-a)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+c^2\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}\,.$$
Observe that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials of degree at most $2$ such that $p(t)=1$ and $q(t)=t^2$ for $t\in\{a,b,c\}$.  Therefore, $p(x)=1$ and $q(x)=x^2$ identically.  If $[x^k]f(x)$ denotes the coefficient of $x^k$ in a polynomial $f(x)$, then we have
$$\begin{align}S&=(a^2+b^2+c^2)\Big([x^2]p(x)\Big)-2\Big([x^2]q(x)\Big)\\&=(a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot 0-2\cdot 1=-2\,.\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, note that
$$S=-\frac{P(a,b,c)}{Q(a,b,c)}\,,$$
where
$$P(a,b,c):=(b^2+c^2-a^2)(b-c)+(c^2+a^2-b^2)(c-a)+(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a-b)$$
and
$$Q(a,b,c):=(b-c)(c-a)(a-b)\,.$$
Note that when two variables are equal, $P(a,b,c)=0$.  Thus, $P(a,b,c)$ is divisible by $Q(a,b,c)$.  This shows that $$P(a,b,c)=k\,Q(a,b,c)$$ for some constant $k$.  Since $P(-1,0,+1)=4$ and $Q(-1,0,+1)=2$, we conclude that $k=2$, whence $S=-k=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here we use $$ab(a-b)+bc(b-c)+ca(c-a)=a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)=-(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$
In short we cab write $$\sum ab(a-b)=\sum a^2(b-c)=-(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)~~~~(1)$$
Then $$F=\frac{a^2+b^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$
$$\implies F=\frac{(a^2+b^2-a^2)(c-b)+(c^2+a^2-b^2)(a-c)+(a^2+b^2-c^2)(b-a)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$
upon simplification in the numerator six terms: $(\pm a^3\pm b^3 \pm c^3)$ will cancel each other, we will get $6+6=12$ terms in the numerator as
$$F=\frac{-\sum a^2(b-c)-\sum ab(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}= 2,$$
on using (1).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Multiply the first term by $ b-c$ to get in the numerator

$$b^3+c^2b-a^2b-b^2c-c^3+a^2c$$
and the others, by permutation

$$c^3+a^2c-b^2c-c^2a-a^3+b^2a$$
$$a^3+b^2a-c^2a-a^2b-b^3+c^2b$$

The result is $  -2$.

Comment: Isn't that what the OP did -- clearing the denominator?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin The OP just said he didn't find .

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  we must have $$a\ne b\ne c$$

Take out the terms containing $b^2$ in the numerator

$$b^2\left(-\dfrac1{(a-b)(c-a)}+\dfrac1{(b-c)(a-b)}-\dfrac1{(c-a)(b-c)}\right)$$

$$=b^2\cdot\dfrac{-(b-c)+c-a-(a-b))}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a}$$

$$=\dfrac{2b^2(c-a)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$$

$$\implies\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{c^2+a^2-b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$
$$=\dfrac2{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}\cdot\left( b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)+a^2(b-c)\right)$$

Now $b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)+a^2(b-c)$

$=b^2(c-a)+c^2a-bc^2+a^2b-ca^2$

$=b^2(c-a)+ca(c-a)-b(c^2-a^2)$

$=(c-a)(b^2-b(c+a)+ca)$

$=\cdots$

$=-(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$